# Dynamic listview with dynamic URL and dynamic Text

Tags: android, android-studio, android-listfragment, dynamic-url

Hi I having output like following

[image]

But I need an output like the following image.

[image]

Here I am having image URLs in an array list, so dynamically it will change image url and also some times some steps will not have images.

Comment: Add a image view after that your text view. and in your image src section just add your images..

Comment: check this: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Heterogenous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) for Image url and [Recyclerview](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/) for the listview. I hope it helps